# Fatal Error using isTablet for mobiledetect library

Tags: php, tablet

I am using [mobiledetect](http://mobiledetect.net) for detect users using different devices. But, when I'm writing this $detect->isTablet() then I am getting the Fatal error. Can anyone please let me know where and what I'm missing?

```
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
```

works as expected.

but

```
if ( $detect->isTablet() ) {
```

gives an error: Call to undefined method Mobile_Detect::isTablet()

Comment: Are these 2 lines in the same code file?

Comment: Yes, on the next line.

Comment: Then are you sure you have the latest version? Recode the line manually in case you have a byte corruption in the source code, **It happens, occasionally**

Comment: I've just tried another idea, like $deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer'); - also fatal for isTablet()

Comment: I can't find any rational solution, I also tried actual lib version

Comment: I downloaded (composer) the code and it worked without a problem, So I have run out of ideas as well

Comment: The next step is probably to crack open the class and make sure that the method actually exists.

Comment: Thank you, I found another library with the same class name - it made the problem, Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because unfortunately another library in a project used the same class name without isTablet() function.